# toggling class name based on route changes using angular-route

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-route-segment

have 3 routes containing 3 forms Im trying to set bootstrap active class on current tab based on the current route in angular.I used angular route module. How can I achieve this. I m attaching the js code please check and help please

[image]

plnkr.co/edit/iTgNTJ74iLzlNx902qfP?p=preview

Comment: reposting this ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758407/adding-or-removing-classes-based-on-route-changes-in-angular/34766589#34766589

Comment: Why didn't u use angular bootstrap library. Your requirement has been implemented as a core feature in that.

Comment: I can use that but I just to know how it can be implement , please let me know

Comment: If u need youchave to use its Javascript code as a directive.

Comment: I m trying to do it by using location service in the rootscope, and ng-class, but no success

Comment: I don't think it will work. Grab the bootstrap tab js as a separate directive and include it with a directive name.

Comment: can you explain why its not working

Comment: Although u can Watch the url change for each tab, you cannot switch the tabs with amgular functions easily

Answer (score 1):

I used this.tab = 1 to default the tab where the class will be "active" first. Here's are my controller additions:

```
angular.module('ciwiseGenledgerApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function () {
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];

    this.tab = 1;
    this.selectTab = function(setTab) {
    this.tab = setTab; 
    };
    this.isSelected = function(checkTab){
    return this.tab === checkTab;
    };
  });
```

I used ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl" in my page. Here's the snippet on the page.

```
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse" ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li ng-class="{ active: ctrl.isSelected(1) }"><a href="#/" ng-click="ctrl.selectTab(1)">Home</a></li>
              <li ng-class="{ active: ctrl.isSelected(2) }"><a ng-href="#/reports" ng-click="ctrl.selectTab(2)">Reports</a></li>
              <li ng-class="{ active: ctrl.isSelected(3) }"><a ng-href="#/admin" ng-click="ctrl.selectTab(3)">Admin</a></li>
              <li ng-class="{ active: ctrl.isSelected(4) }"><a ng-href="#/help" ng-click="ctrl.selectTab(4)">Help</a></li>
              <li ng-class="{ active: ctrl.isSelected(5) }"><a ng-href="#/about" ng-click="ctrl.selectTab(5)">About</a></li>
              <li ng-class="{ active: ctrl.isSelected(6) }"><a ng-href="#/contact" ng-click="ctrl.selectTab(6)">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

My active tab code is independent of the view routing. Here's my app.js. It has the routing code for my views.

```
angular
  .module('ciwiseGenledgerApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'about'
      })
      .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
        controller: 'ContactCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'contact'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });


  $.material.init();
```