# add Bootstrap active class based on route change in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am trying to add a class (bootstrap active class) using Angular ngClass on my navigation menu, based on the path.
navigationMain template:

```
<div class="section">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" style="width:30%">
                <li ng-class="{active: location === '#!/home', nav-item}">
                    <a href="#!/home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li ng-class="{active: location === '#!/resume', nav-item}">
                    <a href="#!/resume">CV</a>
                </li>
                <li ng-class="{active: location === '#!/overviewActivities', nav-item}">
                    <a href="#!/overviewActivities">I-Talent</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.module.js:

```
angular.
    module('iTalentApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'home',
    'resume',
    'navigationMain'
]).controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootscope, $location) {
    $scope.location = $location.path();
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
        $scope.location = $location.path();
    });
});
```

index.html:

```
<body>
    <navigation-main></navigation-main>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
```

And my config:

```
angular.
module('iTalentApp').
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
    function config($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

        $routeProvider.
            when('/home', {
                template: '<home></home>'
            }).
            when('/resume', {
                template: '<resume></resume>'
            }).
            when('/overviewActivities', {
                template: '<overview-activities></overview-activities>'
            }).
            otherwise('/home');
    }
]);
```

I tried to implement the solution to this question, [adding or removing classes based on route changes in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758407/adding-or-removing-classes-based-on-route-changes-in-angular) but to no avail. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

this is what i'm trying to achieve but in a single page with angular, http://plnkr.co/edit/FNwIAU4OgQHlREIfi4BG I got it working except the conditional active class when they are used. (I'm also fairly new to html, css and js)

**edit:**
errormessage:

```
angular.js:14199 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $rootscopeProvider <- $rootscope <- MainCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/unpr?p0=%24rootscopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24rootscope%20%3C-%20MainCtrl
    at angular.js:68
    at angular.js:4563
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4716)
    at angular.js:4568
    at getService (angular.js:4716)
    at injectionArgs (angular.js:4741)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4763)
    at $controllerInit (angular.js:10592)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:9469)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8810)
```

Comment: Check if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22128830/949476

Comment: @dfsq I'm going to be honest, I tried using that but my knowledge of JavaScript is still just not enough to understand where i need to edit that piece of code and where to place it. I found an error message in my log and will edit my question with it if you could take a look?

Comment: You didn't inject $rootScope.

Comment: oh jeez, i injected $rootscope instead of $rootScope. Thank you so much for finding that. It works now! (also needed to remove the nav-item from ng-class, and remove !# from the location expression: location ==='/path')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we found what was wrong in the comments I'll take the time to write an answer for future reference, The problems were:
- spelling error in controller, changed $rootscope into $rootScope,
- wrong use of ng-class syntax, removed nav-item.
- mistake in the expression of ng-class, location==='#!/path' changed into location==='/path'.
Kudos to @dfsq